# Making .json Files from Arrays

Tags: objective-c, c, json, nsarray, converters

Is there any way to convert large NSArray's into .json files? I have so far been successful with converting csv files to .json, but the data I was given was unfortunately not offered in an organized format (arrays).

Comment: If the NSArray contains only NSStrings and NSNumbers then it's a simple matter of using NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject.  Or you can use writeJSONObject:toStream: to go straight to a file (more or less).

Comment: See the spec for NSJSONSerialization: An object that may be converted to JSON must have the following properties:

    1) The top level object is an NSArray or NSDictionary.

    2) All objects are instances of NSString, NSNumber, NSArray, NSDictionary, or NSNull.

    3) All dictionary keys are instances of NSString.

    4) Numbers are not NaN or infinity.

Answer (score 0):

Example code:

```
NSArray *list = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"1", @"2", @"3"];
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:list options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
```

Then you can check JSON via `isValidJSONObject:` method, to be sure that we got valid JSON.

[documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)